# transition using CATransition

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

How can I use CATransition to move from one controller to the next so that the view moves up to show the second window. I want the view from controller 1 to move up and show the view from the second controller. How can I do that?

Here's what I am doing?

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.7f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
transition.type = kCATransitionFromBottom;

[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated: NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.7f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn,kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade, kCATransitionPush, 
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromBottom
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```